# Saving an other type than Plist with IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, plist

This is how I save my mutable array actually.

```
[myMutableArray writeToFile:@"/Users/myUserIdentifier/Desktop/results.plist" atomically:YES];
```

The array contains basically many words and I want a Windows user to be able to read them AND I need them to go back to a new line for each word.

I've tried to add at the end of every words the  tag and then save the file in .html:

```
[myMutableArray writeToFile:@"/Users/myUserIdentifier/Desktop/results.html" atomically:YES];
```

Actually the file is readable but too bad the  tags have been formatted like so:

```
  &lt;br&gt;
```

So Chrome dont understand it as a "go to a new line".

Well, pretty messed up explanation, hope I'll find a soul mate with a messy mind to understand all this stuff!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just want to write an array containing strings to a file?  Nothing fancy needed then.  For example:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *words = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"fluffy",@"furball",@"scratcher",nil];
    FILE *filePointer = fopen("/Volumes/Weinberg/Users/alan/Desktop/cats.txt","w");
    [words enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        fprintf(filePointer,"%s\n",[obj UTF8String]);
    }];
    fclose(filePointer);
    [p release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you try to save the NSMutableArray as an array and then read but
neither works :

```
 - (void)saveState
{
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@\"Layers\" ofType:@\"plist\"];  
NSMutableDictionary* layersDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

[layersDict setValue:layers forKey:@\"Layers\"];
[layersDict writeToFile:filePath atomically: YES];
}

- (void)loadLastState;
{
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@\"Layers\" ofType:@\"plist\"];
NSMutableDictionary* layersDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

NSArray *layersArray = [layersDict objectForKey:@\"Layers\"];

NSMutableArray *layersMutable = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:layersArray];

[self recoverFromLayers:layersMutable];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mhh not really. Everything works fine. I just want to format my result to be a little clearer for a Windows user when launching the file saved. So far, html was the best. But I'm stuck with those  tag. Maybe there is another simple way to get a text file with every words going to the next line.